# Renaming a file using file.move, but adding a string for every new text

Tags: c#

Beginner coder here.

I need to add the GetLastWriteTime string to my filename using the (rename) file.move method. How do I add a string using file.move?

I've looked up some similar info, and I've gotten part of the answer I need. `System.IO.File.Move("oldfilename", "newfilename");` is the code I'll need help with. I tried adding a string to the newfilename, but it only supports directory.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:/foto's", "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

string filename = Path.GetFileName(photo);

DateTime fileCreatedDate = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(filename);

System.IO.File.Move(@"C:\foto's", @"C:\foto's" + fileCreatedDate);
```

Expected error, string cannot be accepted in a directory place.

Comment: You are impicitly using the default format for fileCreatedDate, which contains characters (in particular ":") that are illegal in a file path.  You should try explicitly formatting it to a legal format, e.g. `fileCreatedDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd-HHmmss")`

Answer (score 0):

I've always preferred to use FileInfo objects for stuff like this as they have the dates built in, have MoveTo rather than using the static File.Move etc ...

```
  FileInfo[] fis = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\foto's").GetFiles("*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

  foreach(FileInfo fi in fis){

    //format a string representing the last write time, that is safe for filenames
    string datePart = fi.LastWriteTimeUtc.ToString("_yyyy-MM-dd HH;mm;ss"); //use ; for time because : is not allowed in path

    //break the name into parts based on the .
    string[] nameParts = fi.Name.Split('.');

    //add the date to the last-but-one part of the name
    if(nameParts.Length == 1) //there is no extension on the file
      nameParts[0] += datePart;
    else
      nameParts[nameParts.Length-1] += datePart;

    //join the name back together
    string newName = string.Join(".", nameParts);

    //move the file to the same directory but with a new name. Use Path.Combine to join directory and new file name into a full path
    fi.MoveTo(Path.Combine(fi.DirectoryName, newName));

  }

  Directory.Move(@"c:\foto's", @"c:\photos"); //fix two typos in your directory name ;)
```